# Invoke Root Frame control for Refresh

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

Need to refresh Root frame control once network is disconnected in terminal.

Steps:
If login successful, it redirect to Home page.
Inside home view, child frame set to navigate to another page, but home view is act as master page, it constant.
Now I accessing any child page, but in between if network is disconnected, then it should notify to home view control for status color change.

Can any one suggest.

Comment: Finally, found solution. implement Messenger concept in my application, it workout very smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us which part is confusing that makes you cannot finish your task. Here are something related:

1. I have no idea why network status changed is related to child and main frame. Personally I would register the [NetworkStatusChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj835820(v=win.10)) to detect the network status.
2. I'm not so sure whether you've noticed the official sample. In any official sample you can find this code:

   ```
   rootPage.NotifyUser
   ```

   Actually the NotifyUser method is defined in mainpage and then in the demo page you will call the following code([A simple demo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/File-picker-sample-9f294cba/sourcecode?fileId=43705&pathId=1857783570)):

   ```
   MainPage rootPage = MainPage.Current;
   ```

So if your network changes, you just need to detect the event and then call the rootframe's method to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx

Using MVVM Messenger concept, it help to Send back to my parent page control to refresh.